# Randomly Multiply OR Divide by a Random Number?

Tags: random

I want that Mathematica decides randomly if a given variable, gets multiplied or divided by a random number in a given range.

The "naive" idea to just use

```
RandomReal[{1/10,10}]*X;
```

fails because most of the time `RandomReal[{1/10,10}]` is a number bigger than one because the interval from 1 to 10 is much bigger than the interval from 1/10 to 1, at least for Mathematica. In other words, using this code most of the time the X gets multiplied by a number, i.e. RandomReal[{1/10,10}]>1 and almost never gets divided, i.e. RandomReal[{1/10,10}]<1. In pseudocode, what I want is

```
RandomReal[{1,10}] Random[{*,/}]* X
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would approach this from the fact that both are forms of multiplication, but one has a negative exponent.

So

```
RandomReal[{1, 20}]^RandomChoice[{1, -1}]
```

will randomly be either 1/x or x, where x is a random number between 1 and 20.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the distribution desired, you could use the log-normal (or a similar transformation of whatever distribution has a mean of `0`).  It is transformed distribution such that a value `-y < 0` of the underlying distribution is transformed to `1/x` iff the value `y > 0` is transformed to `x` (i.e., `Exp[-y] == 1/x` where `x = Exp[y]`).  The "underlying" distribution for `LogNormalDistribution[0, s]` is `NormalDistribution[0, s]`, which is symmetrically distributed about `0`.  Thus `x` is as likely as `1/x` in sampling from `LogNormalDistribution[0, 1]`.

```
RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[0, 1]]
RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[0, 1], 10]
```

Transform the uniform distribution:

```
logUniformD = TransformedDistribution[Exp[x],
  x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-2, 2}]]
(*
  TransformedDistribution[E^\[FormalX], \[FormalX] \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{-2, 2}]]
*)

RandomVariate[logUniformD]
RandomVariate[logUniformD, 10]
```

or just simply use `Exp@RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 10]`.

They're roughly just as fast as each other:

```
RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[0, 1], 10^6]; // RepeatedTiming
RandomVariate[logUniformD, 10^6]; // RepeatedTiming
Exp@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 10^6]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.031, Null}
  {0.015, Null}
  {0.010, Null}
*)
```

Here's a visualization of some distributions (JasonB's uniform joined with its inverse, log normal, and log uniform), with binning according with the symmetry `x -> 1/x`:

```
Show[#, Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Automatic}] & /@ 
  Histogram /@ Log /@
    {RandomReal[{1, 10}, 1000]^RandomChoice[{1, -1}, 1000],
     RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[0, 0.85], 1000],
     Exp@RandomReal[{-Log[10], Log[10]}, 1000]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is what I was going to say.  Note, though, that this distribution is "continuously" weighted rather than discretely weighted;  for example, it's much less likely to pick a number between 9 and 10 than between 1 and 2, and less likely to pick a number between 0.9 and 1 than between 0.1 and 0.2.  It's not 100% clear from the question whether this is acceptable.  (It does have a certain elegance to it, though.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, that is what I meant by "depending on the distribution desired" which wasn't clear to me either. Since you can't pick numbers uniformly throughout the interval from 1/A to A to get the property the OP seeks, it would be strange to me to require that the distribution be uniform in a subinterval, say, [1, A].  In any case, I was just showing there are many ways to do it, which might be of more general interest than the OP's particular aims.

Comment: Thank god, someone came up with `Exp@*RandomReal`, +1

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for introducing me to ``Charting`ScaledTicks[  ]``+ 1

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
 RandomChoice[{Times[x, #] &, Divide[x, #] &}][RandomReal[{1, 20}]]
```

To repeat, use a `Table` or `Do` expression, etc.

Comment: Or more compactly, `RandomChoice[{Times, Divide}][x, RandomReal[{1, 20}]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish something very similar to your pseudo-code by defining a function:

```
rand := RandomChoice[{Times, Divide}]
```

Now every time you call the rand function, it either multiplies or divides its two arguments. For example,

```
rand[3, 4]
```

returns 12 half the time and 3/4 the other half. Now you can replace the "4" with a randomly chosen number and replace the "3" with your x.

Answer (score 1):

This gives slightly different results than the other solutions ( if you `Listplot` large data points)

```
RandomChoice[{RandomReal[{1/10, 1}], RandomReal[{1, 10}]}]
```

Comment: More importantly, it gives a different distribution. The inverse of an uniformly distributed variable is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: @celtschk Looks like the distribution in this answer is more uniform for each interval (1/10 to 1 and 1 to 10). I checked the means and it gives around .55 for interval 1/10 to 1 and around 5.5 for interval 1 to 10.

Comment: Yes, exactly: You *multiply with* an uniform distribution between 0.1 and 1. Which is not the same as *dividing by* an uniform distribution between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

Let us dwell a little bit on that and calculate the distribution function (PDF) of the two-fold random factor given by

```
t = u^v
```

where u is assumed here - as an example - to be exponentially distributed and v takes the values +1 or -1 with equal probability 1/2.

The PDF is given by

```
f[t_] := Integrate[
  Exp[-u] (DiracDelta[t - u] + DiracDelta[t - 1/u])/2, {u, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

One by one we have

```
Integrate[((1/2)*DiracDelta[t - u])/E^u, {u, 0, Infinity}]

(* Out[340]= ConditionalExpression[1/2 E^-t HeavisideTheta[t], t \[Element] Reals] *)

Integrate[((1/2)*DiracDelta[t - 1/u])/E^u, {u, 0, Infinity}]

(* Out[341]= ConditionalExpression[(E^(-1/t) Boole[t > 0])/(2 Abs[t]^2), t > 0] *)
```

Together, and simplified we find for the PDF

```
f2 = Simplify[% + %%, t > 0]

(* Out[342]= 1/2 (E^-t + E^(-1/t)/t^2) *)
```

f2 is finite for all t, and it has a small local minimum close to t = 0.

The normalization is ok

```
Integrate[f2, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[343]= 1 *)
```

But it can be easily shown that higher moments do no exist because of the long tail of the distribution.

*Addendum*

I have noticed on more careful reading the answers that Michael E2 has considered explicit distributions earlier. But I think the developments complement each other.